# Can we manipulate Angular routerlink redirection from an external code base?

Tags: angular, iframe

my code sits on an Iframe wrapped by an Angular framework. I want to prevent the Angular routerLink from getting invoked when user clicks on any  links on the browser. Basically prevent the redirection and invoke some functions in my code. Is it possible to do it from my code base itself?

I have tried e.preventDefault() and javascript:void(0) on the  elements, changing the href to "#" or removing href entirely but the redirection still happened.

[Image to illustrate the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05asA.png)

Comment: please show some code so we can better understand. and are you talking about the links inside the angular iFrame or outside?

Comment: Hi, sorry I do not have access to the Angular code hence unable to provide snippets. But I have added an illustration of the application on my question.

I am talking about when user clicking on the links outside of the iFrame (menu item 1, 2, 3 etc) , which belongs to the Angular application. Can my application, which resides inside the iframe, stops the redirection and show something before the redirection happens?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. An iFrame can't influence the behaviour of it's parent application. (and the other way around is also not possible).

This is probably for security reasons, if you think about it, it make sense. Let's say facebook has an iFrame, so my iFrame would affect the behaviour of the whole facebook page... that would be bad.

Comment: But what if the iFrame and parent application are from the same domain?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter